# Заменить название вкладки "Реакции" на "Уведомления"

Tags: предложение, локализация

На странице участника, на вкладке "Реакции", которая находится здесь [https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/твой_id/твой_позывной?tab=responses](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_id/%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9?tab=responses) отображается список уведомлений о действиях происходящих с твоими сообщениями: об ответах к ним, о правках, сделанных другими и т.п. Исходя из сути предлагаю заменить название вкладки на "Уведомления".

Почему не "Реакции"?

Потому что суть понятия "реакция" (англ: re-action) заключается в ответном действии на первоначальное. Когда кто-то правит твоё трёхлетнее сообщение и тебе отображается число, уведомляющее об этом, то это не может считаться "реакцией" по причине отсутствия первоначального усилия, которого, в данное время, тобою выполнено не было.

Comment: Ну да, "реакция" - это ответка. Всё верно. Правка/комментарий/ответ. А уведомления не обязательно в ответ на что-то.

Comment: Тогда "Голоса" тоже нужно поместить в "Реакции", ибо это также является ответкой.

Comment: «Ответка/обратка» тоже хорошие варианты

Comment: @defaultlocale по-братски.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica На следующее первое апреля можно сделать всю локализацию в таком стиле.

Answer (score 3):

"Уведомления" ассоциируется с уведомлениями наверху. Но "реакции" мне тоже не очень нравится. Как насчёт "обновления"?

Comment: Замечу, что в оригинале там "Responses".

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica исходите из сути. Неудачно назвать могут и создатели.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, ну мы не можем перевести как "ответы", потому что они у нас для "answers".

Comment: «Отклики» же :)

Comment: @defaultlocale, что-то я не уверен, что правка сообщения - это отклик. Но ты можешь предложить эту версию отдельным ответом.